# What is the best practice for a CMS like SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, cms

Before diving into detail please read my former question for further details:

[Replacing a custom-developed CMS tool with SharePoint?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/44929/replacing-a-custom-developed-cms-tool-with-sharepoint)

To sum-up, I need to create-develop a sharepoint site to replace some custom developed CMS site. The thing is, i will need some custom UI for managing content. Because as the structure will be sites and sub-sites and some contents in those sites, content authors will have to go to different sub-sites to add content. I think this is not best-practice, i think i should have some custom web parts or application pages, for content authors to easily add-edit contents for any level of sites.

I have sharepoint development experience, so all custom development ideas are welcome.

What is the best practice for these kind of CMS requirements in SharePoint structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience, the best way to look at it is this
Custom look and UI, deploy a custom master page.
Custom UI actions and operations, work with lists and custom web parts.
With the sharepoint libraries and C# you can do anything you will need and if you can create dynamic and useful web parts, it will make everyones' life easier.

Comment: very thanks. although it is some kind of blurry in my mind, i was thinking about exactly what you have told. could you be technically one step deeper in the point of a developer.

Comment: Of course, but I am still trying to figure out what you are trying to do and what you are having trouble with. Are you wondering how to deploy to child sites? or how to add web parts on each page? or how to make a site template?

Comment: I am blurry about how-to setup the structure. In current CMS tool, there are admin screens which authors can add-edit hierarchical menus, add-edit content items (that are rich-text) and associate the content-items with the menu items. How to map this kind of application to sharepoint and what to develop?

Comment: So an end user must be able to define hierachical menus? you thing you could is create a custom xml schema and a web part that allows the editing and uploading of these xml file (wrapped so they don't know it is an xml file) then have a web part or just a list that they can upload content. In the menu web part (these could be the same web part/page) you could load their articles and insert the ID's into the xml to associate them. Now you have a list of xml documents whcih you can define metadata to. These xml files can now be loaded into a view web part and comsumed wherever they are needed

Comment: Thanks, and what do you think about the content pages.I think i should have some custom web parts that have UI to dynamically create pages and adding the content to those pages?

Comment: I think that is the best way to do it